# Are there any safer Dropbox alternatives?

Tags: cloud, dropbox

Are there **safer** alternatives for dropbox? As someone who knows my mailadress basically only is a password away from my personal data.

Comment: The same goes for most online things - including this site. I think dropbox does notification when you sync a new computer, though not when someone accesses the web interface. This question will likely be closed as too broad/opinion based, because they are many alternatives that could be used - could you perhaps add some more information to the question, what you have tried etc? (Note: [Ubuntu One has pretty must stopped for good](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/))

Comment: @jmunsch - neat suggestion - if you look at [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QRW6H.png) it seems to have the same authentication system as dropbox - just email and password. **empedokles** - if you are worried about people accessing your dropbox, you can check under https://www.dropbox.com/account#security. Wait, just spotted something...

Comment: @Wilf : You are right. Apologies.

Comment: @jmunsch - doesn't matter, just a point - you should of kept the link, it looked rather good  :D

Comment: Originally linked: http://askubuntu.com/questions/299443/how-do-i-install-copy-file-syncing-software

Comment: Has copyagent also a security code option?

Comment: This makes no sense to me "mail address only a password away from your personal data"

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1068777/790920 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use Two-step verification instead - you then need your mobile phone or another device to sign into Dropbox:

[image: Enable two-step verification screenshot]

Go to [`https://www.dropbox.com/account#security`](https://www.dropbox.com/account#security), and you can enable it. You can find out more on it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/363/en) (note the 'advanced' section for Linux users - guess what I'll be trying later... :D ).

Also note that, the best thing would be to have a really secure passwords *(you can generate some nice ones with `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 20`)*, as well as using different passwords for different sites, especially with the same email.

And perhaps also check from where Dropbox has been/is being accessed under the the [Dropbox Security tab](https://www.dropbox.com/account#security):
[image: dropbox web interface log screenshot]

You also may want to enable these Email Alert options under Dropbox's Profile Preferences:
[image: Email alert: A new something is linked to dropbox]

Answer (score 0):

You could try SpiderOak.  The last time I looked they supported Linux.