# Install Windows 7 and remove Ubuntu without harming any personal files

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, uninstall

Ok,Because Ubuntu doesnt run many programmes and isnt user friendly, i want to remove it (14.04 LTS) but, I have a lot of personal files and no hard disk to back them in and have windows 7 pro on my bootable pen drive. Could anyone help me out? I am a beginner so, Step by step process preferred.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have a few Pointers to for you. Though I hate it that you are moving away from Ubuntu to Windows 7.

I have been a Windows System Architect for my whole life, My bread and butter is because of Microsoft's Software. However I still use Linux/Ubuntu on all my personal Systems because Linux is superior to Windows in Every Possible Way.

With that out of the way, Here is the solution for you.

1) You can recover your Data from Ubuntu back to Windows without an External Drive, Only if you already have a Windows Installation on the Same system. Which means you should have a Dual Boot System.

2) The problem is that Linux can see your Windows Partition and File Systems, But Windows Can't see anything except FAT FAT32 NTFS or exFAT file Systems.

3) If you have already got rid of Windows7 in favor of Ubuntu, I would say reconsider Using Ubuntu, However if you have made up your mind,You really have only one option. BACKUP YOUR DATA TO A CLOUD SERVICE OR A FILE SHARE OR AN EXTERNAL Drive.

Comment: If That is the only option, that is what I will Do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a shame to hear that you are leaving Ubuntu. I too can understand your frustration, but if you stick with it, it is all worth it in the end. I too was frustrated, but stuck with it as I was fed up of windows trying to rule the world.
Now I personally feel that the gui is more user friendly that most others. With regards to the programs, you have the option of using Wine to run windows files. Also there are so many alternatives to the mainstream programs in the software centre and they are all free. Yes it takes a bit to get used to them, but when you are not paying you don't seem to mind as much.

If you have not got drive to back your files on to, have a look at installing an on-line cloud folder such as 'Copy'. I have this and it is good. You could back up stuff to it and know it is safe. This link will show you how to do it:

[Install Copy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299443/how-do-i-install-copy-file-syncing-software)

Have you thought about setting up a virtual box to install windows within ubuntu until you can sort things out. That way you can have both at the same time and know that your files are safe.

Comment: Well, I would back up my data in form of a cloud but it is 300+ GBs... So. Well You know... And when it comes to the software center, Ubuntu doesnt even have Paint! I downloaded an alternative but it was way too complicated for me to understand.

Comment: GNUPaint, Tuxpaint, understand that wanting to run all your windows programs and games with wine is just not going to work like you aimed in one of your previous questions "wine program doesn't run 90% of the games" . If you want to run only  Windows programs install Windows.

Comment: Well If only this question was on- "How to install Windows".

Answer (score 0):

Before uninstalling anything, in Ubuntu open the file manager( looks like a file cabinet) and mount your Windows partition by just clicking on it. Find the files you want to save and cut and paste to the Windows drive in a directory you are familiar with. Next open a terminal and type: locate mbr.bin  Next write down the location then type: dd if=(the location)/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda This should write over the grub that boots Ubuntu. Once back in Windows open Adminstrator services and go to disk storage. You will be able to delete the drive the Ubuntu os was on.

Comment: That Sounds like a good easy way. But as I am a Beginner to Ubuntu and do not even know what file cabinet looks like, I am not able to find the file manager. Please help me out

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu and using the Unity Do this.. Press the Windows/Super Key on your Keyborad.. and Type files. The fist search result you get is the File Manager. Click on it and it will ope the File manager. Then look for your Windows partition in the Lower Left Side. Cick on it to mount it.(This is true only if you have Dual booted your System.) Then you can copy over you Personal Files from UBuntu to Windows7

Comment: No dual boot system. And The pendrive is just 8GBs in space...